# Export actionscript and raw data structure from swf wire

Tags: flash, decompiling, swf-decompiler

I've come across swf wire in the past few days as a nice way of decompiling swf files, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to actually get the decompiled files into a place that is useful for me. Is there anyone that knows how to export the pure text from swf wire inspector without having to copy and paste each file? Is there some better free swf decompiler I should use that will make my life easier?